# Particle system in Evee only rendering in half my screen

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

The issue is my rain particles are only rending on the left half of the screen as you can see here:  [image: Rendered]

However, I know that they are dropping as you can see here in blender:
[image]

What I find odd is that if I zoom in to view, they will disappear in the same region that they are not rending, even though I'm not changing the camera. As seen here:

[image]

I am simply zooming the window in while the camera stays in the same position. This made me think it was a graphics card issue that would work itself out in the render, but as you can see it persist there as well. I find this behavior vary peculiar and am not sure how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!